# How to design this table to include multiple names of people

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this database table that keeps track of projects, who is assigned to them, and their status. Everything works fine as it is, but I now need to add fields for another person to be able to be added to the table.

Right now, only one person (First and Last Name) can be assigned to a project, but I need that to be able to accept two people (first and last names).

Right now all I can think to do is either:
a) add two more columns for first and last name of the 2nd person, or
b) merge the first and last names into one 'Name' and have two columns for person1 and person2.

What would be the best way to handle this? (The screenshot included is fictional data)

[image]

Comment: What you have here is a many-to-many relatiionship. You need to create a new table, which store the ID of the project and the user, and then define a foreign key between each to the Project/User tables.

Comment: Just to be clear, what I should do is keep the project table consisting of Project ID, Type, Status, and Last Updated --- then make a new User table consisting of Project ID, and the names?

Comment: You would have 3 tables, not 2.

Comment: @Larnu sorry I'm not following, can you point out what the 3rd table would be?

Edit: Perhaps I could have a Projects table, User table, and an Assigned To table?

Answer (score 2):

Best way to implement this in a relational database is to add a new table ProjectAssignees with 1-N relation from Projects table. That way you can secure future requirements such as assignee roles and etc.

Answer (score 1):

The futur proof version would be to add new tables (or at least one new table) where you could link your project ID with a user ID (or with a first + last name).
By doing that, you could have 1 or more people working on a project

Comment: This makes sense. Once I have all of the tables created I would then be able to join them in order to get a view similar to what I have in the screenshot?

Comment: Yes, by getting all the users working on the project you want ("P102" for example).
But just to be clear, you'll do that only when needed, you wont actually fuse the tables themselves.

Comment: Right, I would only join them in a query. I'm going to give this a shot

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a many-to-many relatiionship. You need to create a new table, which store the ID of the project and the user, and then define a foreign key between each to the Project/User tables.

In overly simplified terms, it would look something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Project (ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                          ProjectType varchar(10),
                          ProjectStatus varchar(10));
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Users (ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                        FirstName nvarchar(50),
                        Surname nvarchar(50));
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ProjectUsers (ProjectID int NOT NULL,
                               UserID int NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE dbo.ProjectUsers ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ProjectUser PRIMARY KEY (ProjectID, UserID);
ALTER TABLE dbo.ProjectUsers ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ProjectUser_Project FOREIGN KEY (ProjectID) REFERENCES dbo.Project (ID);
ALTER TABLE dbo.ProjectUsers ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ProjectUser_User FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES dbo.Users (ID);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Project (ProjectType,ProjectStatus)
VALUES('a','b'),('c','d');
INSERT INTO dbo.Users(FirstName, Surname)
VALUES('John','Smith'),('Jane','Brown');
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.ProjectUsers
VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(2,1);
GO
--Sample query
SELECT P.*, U.* --Don't really use *
FROM dbo.Project P
     JOIN dbo.ProjectUsers PJ ON P.ID = PJ.ProjectID
     JOIN dbo.Users U ON PJ.UserID = U.ID;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.ProjectUsers;
DROP TABLE dbo.Project;
DROP TABLE dbo.Users;
```